# Uploading image in django: getting "global name context is not defined" error

Tags: django, image

I am trying to upload an image using django and following a tutorial from a website. In `views.py` I have:

```
def picture_upload(request):
    """
    form to upload an image together with a caption.
    saves it as a Picture in the database on POST.
    shows the last uploaded picture and let's you upload another.
    """
    picture = None
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = PictureUploadForm()
    else:
        form = PictureUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # an UploadedFile object
            uploadedImage = form.cleaned_data['image']
            caption = form.cleaned_data['caption']

            # limit to one database record and image file.
            picture, created = Picture.objects.get_or_create(picture_id=1)
            if not created and picture.get_image_filename():
                try:
                    os.remove( picture.get_image_filename() )
                except OSError:
                    pass

            # save the image to the filesystem and set picture.image
            picture.save_image_file(
                uploadedImage.filename, 
                uploadedImage.content
            )

            # set the other fields and save it to the database
            picture.caption = caption
            picture.save()

            # finally, create a new, empty form so the 
            # user can upload another picture.
            form = PictureUploadForm()

    return render_to_response(
        'example/picture_upload.html',
        Context(dict( form=form, last_picture=picture) ) )
```

The error says:

> global name 'Context' is not defined" at last line of my code. "views.py in picture_upload, line 111".

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If its not defined, it's not defined. You'd have to import Context from django.template.

At the top of your file, type in

```
from django.template import Context
```

You can't magically hope that all variables are defined... would you think you could use `PictureUploadForm` if you had not imported it or otherwise defined it?

Comment: Sometimes I like to think I can use things that I haven't imported, because I'm special.

Comment: Actually there's no need to use `Context` here at all. `render_to_response` (and the newer `render`) are quite happy with a normal dict.

Comment: Make sure from django.template import Context - context is all lower case - with C it did not work. Thank you that helped me.